# How to add Expires to HttpHeader of HttpClient in c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I am trying to call an api from an external application from my c# code. (.Net core 2.2)
I am using `HttpClient` for this. While I tried to add `Expires` to the header, it is getting removed from the request while it is called (I inspected through Fiddler). I am adding an authentication token in the similar manner, and it is getting added to the headers correctly.

I am getting `401` error from the api.

The following is my code:

```
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri.Uri);
            var xml = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml");
            var json = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json", 0.8);

            req.Headers.Accept.Clear();           
            req.Headers.Accept.Add(json);



            // First try
            //req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "H** ********:MApmTuFFV5nZJOg+i5gRBPkM**0=");
            //req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Expires", "10/02/19 10:36:33 AM UTC");

            // Second try
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "H** ********:MApmTuFFV5nZJ**+i5gRBPkM**0=");
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Expires", "10/02/19 10:36:33 AM UTC");

            // Third try
            //req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "H** ********:MApmTuFFV5nZJOg+i5gRBPkM**0=");
            // req.Headers.Add("Expires", "10/02/19 10:36:33 AM UTC");

             try
             {
                using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.SendAsync(req))
                 {
                    response.ResponseStatusCode = res.StatusCode;
                    response.ResponseStatusDescription = string.Format("HttpStatusCode: {0} \n StatusDescription: {1}", res.StatusCode.ToString(), res.StatusCode);

                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                        {
                            response.ResponseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

The api call was done using `HttpWebRequest`, and the same works good, when I changed it to `HttpClient`, I am getting `401 UnAuthorized` as the response from api:
The earlier code is:

```
string uri = "http://someservice.com"
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

            req.Method = "Get";
            req.Accept = "application/json";
            req.KeepAlive = true;

                req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Expires] = "10/02/19 10:36:33 AM UTC";
                req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "H** ********:MApmTuFFV5nZJ**+i5gRBPkM**0=";


            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    response.ResponseStatusCode = res.StatusCode;
                    response.ResponseStatusDescription = string.Format("HttpStatusCode: {0} \n StatusDescription: {1}", res.StatusCode.ToString(), res.StatusDescription);

                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            response.ResponseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }                    
                }
            }
```

Can some one please point out the issue in my approach?

Comment: The `Expires` header per RFC is a response header, not a request header.  An example of the HTTP Date format is `Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT`.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.3

Comment: You cant expire request data.

Comment: also, 401 means "unauthorized". the token you are sending is either wrong or in the wrong format.